# Android: Dynamically starting an activity

Tags: android, android-intent

I would like to dynamically start an activity based on the previous activity's input. I have input a string through the previous activity, the only thing is this specific code throws the error

cannot resolve constructor 'Intent(com.MentalMathWorkout.EasyCountDown, java.lang.String)'

Is there a way to make this work?

```
public class EasyCountDown extends AppCompatActivity {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_ecd);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String test = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.TEST_TYPE);
    String cstring = ".class";
    final String activity = test.concat(cstring);

    Intent intent = new Intent(EasyCountDown.this, activity);
    startActivity(intent); //Start test
}
```

Comment: EasyCountDown inherits from...?

Comment: I think you could try with Java Reflection. Or implement one static method in each activity with the next activity or one set of activities to select throught one param each one of them, complex enum would be another option... There're a lot of possibilites really.

Comment: This is a cooler solution, but why cant you use a simple switch case?

Comment: use the `ComponentName` object, which does exactly what you are looking for

Comment: @njzk2 your solution is great (+1 and should be accepted: I would have gone for reflection, so knowing that there is ComponentName is a boon), but Nanoc has a case here. Unless the OP is thinking about some kind of debugging rig, or is just doing this for the sake of it, a switch/if/Map/whatever is a less generic, but safer solution, imo (even if the intent is checked for null)...

Comment: @Rick77 absolutely. Unless you have a good reason to use the activity name, using the class object directly is much better

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ComponentName object does just that:

```
String activity = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.TEST_TYPE);
Intent intent = new Intent(this, new ComponentName(this, activity));
startActivity(intent);
```

That's assuming `this` is an instance of `Activity`. (for a `Fragment`, use `getActivity()`, obv.)

Answer (score 1):

I have a class on here:

```
com.yasinkacmaz.newproject.activity.ProfileActivity
```

My test string like that:

```
"com.yasinkacmaz.newproject.activity.ProfileActivity"
```

And it working good:

```
public  class EasyCountDown extends AppCompatActivity {
    final Activity thisActivity = this;
    private Intent previousIntent,nextIntent;

     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.your_layout);

        previousIntent = getIntent();
        String test = previousIntent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.TEST_TYPE);
        final String activity = test;
        Class newclass = null;

        try {
          newclass = Class.forName(activity);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException c) {
            c.printStackTrace();
        }

        if(newclasss != null) {
            nextIntent = new Intent(thisActivity, newclass);
            startActivity(nextIntent);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"new class null",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Dont forget you can use switch case or etc., because in this way you can get `ClassNotFoundException` and your intent will be `null`.

Comment: You don't need cstring here at all. And extra TEST_TYPE should be init with `<DesiredActivity>.class.getCanonicalName()`

Comment: @tommus why delete my strong string , there is important notice was there :(

Comment: @YasinKaçmaz - You should use bolded text / quotes / etc. sparingly.

Comment: @tommus thanks , very constructive way to help  me :)