# Android start intent via string name

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-intent

```
 String c="MainActivty.class";       
 Intent ints =new Intent(getApplication(),c);
 startActivity(ints);
```

How can i do this on the click of the button i.e specify c to an Intent,or is there any other way i can do this?

The problem is that i have set c to intent but it is not working.

Comment: You want to start an intent when you click on a button??

Comment: Yes i want to start intent when click on the button

Comment: Why wouldn't you just use the `Class`?

Comment: no i want to set string to intent , that is the problem

Comment: @Mike M. because the string is dynamic. it can be MainActivity4 or 5 or 6, anything

Comment: If you're expecting the user to enter a class name, that's not good design. Otherwise, there's really no need to do what you're attempting, since you know all of your classes and their names when you write the code.

Comment: Basically i am bookmarking it , or you can say that user will be able to set add to favourite any page.

Comment: You could create an array of your classes, and save the indexes as the bookmarks.

Comment: ok good idea, any built in framework you know about?

Comment: @Mike M  any built in framework about bookmarking you know about?

Comment: Uh, not really. However you were planning to save your bookmarks, you'd just be saving `int`s for the indexes, instead of your `String`s. E.g., create your array like so: `Class<?>[] activities = new Class<?>[numActivities]; activities[0] = MainActivity0.class; ...`, and create an `Intent` like so: `new Intent(context, activities[0])`. Other than that, `SharedPreferences` would probably be sufficient to store the bookmark indexes.

Answer (score 1):

I understand your problem , so many guys giving you - point :

Lets assume i have a class here : `com.mydomain.myproject.activity.MyActivity`

And string must be like : `"com.mydomain.myproject.activity.MyActivity"`

then start intent like :

```
Class newclass = null;
//add this outside of OnCreate
final Activity thisActivity = this;
String activityString="com.mydomain.myproject.activity.MyActivity";
    try {
      newclass = Class.forName(activityString);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException c) {
        c.printStackTrace();
    }

    if(newclasss != null) {
        nextIntent = new Intent(thisActivity, newclass);
        startActivity(nextIntent);
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"new class null",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Also another good answer is here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/37060977/5047398

Answer (score 1):

There is not Constructor Intent(Context context, String s). So you can't pass a String to create a Intent. You can only use a String to set the Action of that Intent. The Constructor that you are trying to use takes as second argument a Class cls not a String. When you use Intent(getContext(), "MainActivity.class") the compiler does not create a String it creates a Class instance.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html

Comment: I didn't say that i am doing this. i said how can i pass class not knowing at runtime, what class it is to intent

Comment: In that case you may create a numbers of intent, and then based in a button click, a variable, a sharedpreferences key or something, i will start the corresponding intent.